# Expo react native doesn't request location permission

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, android-permissions

I'm building an app that needs to track user's locations for app functionality. I'm requesting user's location using expo Location

```
useEffect(() => 
{
  (async ()=>{

   var {granted}=await Location. 
   requestForegroundPermissionsAsync() 
   // if granted do something

   })()
}, [])
```

The app asks for user's permission the first time, but if user selects "allow only this time" option,closes the app and reopens it, app doesn't ask the location permission again. How can I request permission again on app start if user previously user selected "only this time".

Answer (score 1):

check the location permission first using this code in useEffect

```
 PermissionsAndroid.check(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    );
```